# inline nav example doesn't work

Tags: html, css

```
<style type=”text/css”>

.toolbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #f3f3f3 #bbb #bbb #f3f3f3;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5em;
    zoom: 1;    
}

</style>

<ul class=”toolbar”>
    <li><a href=”#”>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>About us</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Products</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href=”#”>Contact us</a></li>    
</ul>
```

I copied this code from a tutorial but the result is different. I want to have my list in one line, not on 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change curly quotes `”` to valid double `"` or single `'`.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucx8e/)